# Writing a file backup utility in C#

Tags: c#, security, backup, ntfs

**--BEGIN RANT--**

ALL I want to do is copy the "Documents and Settings" folder to back it up in Windows Server 2003, so we can grab old files from it, as needed, easily, after I wipe the server to upgrade the OS to Windows Server 2008.
BUT, I get errors about NTUSER being in use, etc., when I try to copy it.
It's VERY irritating that an administrator can't just use Windows explorer to copy folders, but what-ever.

I don't have time to jump through security hoops, wiping out permissions.
I don't have time to initiate a HUGE folder copy only to have it fail some random % through the operation when it runs into an open file handle.
I don't have time to repeat this process over and over, hunting down the open file handle and closing it with process explorer each time, destabilizing the system as a side effect.

**--END RANT--**

I understand that a user-mode process can have some kind of flag that allows it to bypass NTFS security.

- How do I give this "backup" role (`SE_BACKUP_NAME`/`SE_RESTORE_NAME`) to a process, such as a C# program?
- Can it be done in managed code (or am I gonna have to dig up Win32 API docs, or hand-write manifests and embed them who-knows-where, or track down some obscure backup-program-registration command-line-utility)?
- How do I open a file in C# with backup semantics, so I can copy the file?
- Will open file handles (with exclusive read-locks) interfere with reading the file for backup purposes, or will opening it with backup semantics take care of that, and temporarily suspend writing to the file while it's opened for backup?

I'm asking here, because it's useful information to remain on-record at stackoverflow, that someone probably can spout off the top of their head, that I don't have time to look up myself.  Thank you.

Soon enough, I'll be upgrading some servers to the nightmare that is Windows Server 2008 and learning the icacls command utility, thanks to Microsoft removing GUI support for editing security on multiple folders/files (smart move. not.)

Comment: Why can't you just use an already-created backup utility? That way you wouldn't have to worry about those things that caused you to "rant" in the first place.

Comment: You won't be able to open `NTUSER.DAT` even with backup semantics, because Windows opens it with `FILE_SHARE_NONE`. Just run your backup job while the target user is logged off.

Comment: If all you need are the user-created files, don't worry about backing up `NTUSER.DAT` at all.

Comment: @Michael: Existing backup utilities tend to package things, and include extra information and files that I don't need.  They don't offer the simplicity of copy/paste for backups that Windows Explorer does.
@Anton: So opening with backup semantics does not override exclusive read-locks, and all users must be logged off to do a backup?  I find that hard to believe, not to mention impractical in many cases.
@Ian: Yeah, that would be nice if after pressing Ctrl+C in explorer, it gave me the option to exclude certain files, rather than just failing when it runs into them, but it doesn't offer that.

Comment: Also, if the backup utility is not included in the OS, or I didn't write it myself, then I have no way of being CERTAIN that it's doing the job I want it to do.  I have reason to believe that the manufacturer of the OS can write a working backup-utility for it, and I know what goes on in my own code, but I cannot trust such a thing to a third party.  It's important that Microsoft make writing custom utilities for this kind of thing easy.

Comment: I know what goes on in my own code too.  Which is why I don't trust it.  If I were paranoid enough about backup reliability to write my own utility, the first thing I'd do is develop a test suite to prove its reliability.  A nice side-effect of developing such a test suite is that I could then test existing backup solutions.  Perhaps I wouldn't need to write my own.

Comment: @Robert.  I think you missed the point.  I know what my own code does.  I know whether it's going to skip NTUSER or not, because I tell it to or I don't... the source code is there for me to see, and I'm familiar with it.  A third party utility may be undocumented, and the source code may not be available for becoming familiar with it, and the program may behave differently under special conditions (which you won't know unless it's documented or you have the source code AND become very familiar with it).

Comment: @Robert.  It's not about paranoia; it's about knowing the details of what the program does or does not do.  For example, do you know for certain whether Windows Backup ever, under any circumstances, would skip any kind of a file at all, without any kind of error message?  I don't.  Can one be certain that every aspect of the program's behavior is documented, given that one had nothing to do with it's development?  Of course not.  If you're willing to gamble like that, be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [Microsoft Synchronization Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sync) to create my own Backup & Restore application to migrate user profiles and other related files. The Sync Framework at least has the option to fail silently and continue without prompting when a file is in use, which is the behavior I wanted.

Since it is a synchronization framework it has some ability related to Conflict management. I didn't need them, but it also has other 'providers' for Database and Web synchronization, in addition to the File Sync.

Maybe running the program remotely using [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) can reduce the number of files in use. In my case I only cared about the "current" user so the program was run by the local user and backed up files to a Network Share.

The Sync Framework did require an MSI installation, but I did that with PSExec too.